# The last else statement not executing

Tags: python

When I enter a score greater than 1.0 the last else statement won't execute and it won't print "Value out of range" line. 
The code is given below:

```
score = float(raw_input("Enter Score: "))

if score>= 0.0:

    if score <= 1.0:
        if score >= 0.9:
            print 'A'
        elif score >= 0.8:
            print 'B'
        elif score >= 0.7:
            print 'C'
        elif score >= 0.6:
            print 'D'
        else:
            print 'F'
else:   
    print 'Value out of range'
```

Comment: Double-check your indentation, it's important in Python... Alternatively, simplify the logic - make that first line `if 0.0 <= score <= 1.0:`

Comment: Indent the last two lines one level.

Comment: Yeah thanks. Its working now.

Comment: The last `else` statement should only be executed if `score` is less than 0.0, because it handles the case that isn't matched by `score >= 0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if score >= 0.0 and score <= 1.0:
    if score >= 0.9:
        print 'A'
    elif score >= 0.8:
        print 'B'
    elif score >= 0.7:
        print 'C'
    elif score >= 0.6:
        print 'D'
    else:
        print 'F'
else:   
    print 'Value out of range'
```

Or,

```
if score>= 0.0:   
    if score <= 1.0:
        if score >= 0.9:
            print 'A'
        elif score >= 0.8:
            print 'B'
        elif score >= 0.7:
            print 'C'
        elif score >= 0.6:
            print 'D'
        else:
            print 'F'
    else:   
        print 'Value out of range'
```

Comment: @downvoters some comments would allow me to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is because your else belongs to "score >= 0.0" and not to the "score <= 1.0" clause.
this is indicated by the indentation in python.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the "else" statement to wrong "if"
Have a look at the code once again.

In python indentation blocks are made with spaces so u have to be careful about it.

If u have experience with any other programming language It is like when you would place code inside "{}" insted of outside, in language that uses bracets to indentation

Answer (score -1):

Because `score = 1.0 >= 0.0 == True`

Try instead:

```
if score >= 0.0 and score < 1.0:
```